# Console application is shown as "Running" when it has actually completed

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-task

I created a task in Task Scheduler to run the following C# Hello World program. 
When I trigger it wait for it to complete, I can confirm under in its history that the console application have finished executing. **However**, under the Status column of my scheduled task, it shows that it's still running. What's up with the contradiction?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Scheduled Task]

Comment: I notice the same thing on my machines. Try refreshing.

Comment: Even after a "refresh" of the Task Scheduler console ? if yes, check if the process is still running using task manager.

Comment: Agreed with both notes - The task scheduler view in Win7/Server 2008 does not appear to auto-refresh.

Comment: You guys are right. The Task Scheduler doesn't auto-refresh the status of the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a root around with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  You might find that an instance of CONHOST.EXE is still lurking around (i.e.: an instance spawned for your console app).  Now, I haven't done any C coding since ~1997, and that was with Borland C++ (i.e.: pre .NET framework).  However, your code doesn't have an explicit return code - not sure if this would cause the Task Scheduler to not detect an exit.  Unlikely, but worth a punt.

Comment: I tried explicitly stating a return code of 0 but that doesn't solve the issue. The issue is that the Task Scheduler doesn't auto-refresh as @Psychoholic has pointed out in the comments.